# Remove background from SwiftUI's List in iOS 16

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, wwdc

This is probably an old issue. but I still couldn't find a workable solution.

Like the image below. I want to have the blue background extended to the whole list view on top. However, SwiftUI automatically adds two white backgrounds(potential from UICollection View or somewhere). Does anyone knows how to remove those white backgrounds from the SwiftUI's List?

[image]

[image]

Minimal Code to reproduce the issue. Here the two backgrounds are black and blocks out the blue background.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Hello World")
            Text("Hello World")
            Text("Hello World")
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS 16 you need to use [.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/scrollcontentbackground(_:)) in addition to setting background color:

```
List {
    Text("Hello World")
    Text("Hello World")
    Text("Hello World")
}
.background(Color.blue)
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

Prior to iOS 16, there was a few workarounds, the most reliable one was with retrospect ([example](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708085))

Comment: Awesome, I totally missed that API, thank you so much! Together with .listRowBackground(Color.clear) I got a totally transparent List~~

Comment: Hey bro, I have a problem and want to ask you. When the list is empty, the background will turn white or black. I can't got a transparent List!! HELP!

Comment: @DoubleShy0N well, comments are not the best way to start a new question. Post your question(with code to reproduce the problem) instead, and someone will respond.